# Internal structure of SentiWordNet 3

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, wordnet, senti-wordnet

I am working on a project of Sentiment analysis that uses `SentiwordNet3` lexicon. The problem is, I am unable to understand the structure of lexicon. One line of this Lexicon is:

> a  00002730    0   0   acroscopic#1    facing or on the side toward the apex

**1.** `a`=? Purpose of `a`?

**2.** `POS-ID=00002730`. What is the purpose of `POS-ID`?

**3.** `SynsetTerms Gloss` = `acroscopic#1 facing or on the side toward the apex`

1. What is `acroscopic` ? Is it word that we want the score of?
2. What is `#1`? Purpose?
3. Why is the sentence after `#1`?  `facing or on the side toward the apex`.

As far as the accessing of score is concerned, we accessed it as

```
`list(SWN.senti_synsets(Tagged[i][0],'a')`
```

`a` is `Adjective` whereas `v`,`r` and `n` are also in the lexicon.

Answer (score 0):

The corpus has a header containing the definition of the columns:

## POS   ID  PosScore    NegScore    SynsetTerms Gloss

1. POS 'a' is the part of speech (adjective)
2. ID is the unique identifier of the lemma in Wordnet
3. PosScore => The positive score
4. NegScore => The negative score
5. SynsetTerms => Wordnet synset names (#1 = the first sense, #2 = the second sense)
6. Explanatory sentence

Comment: So, if we give `list(SWN.senti_synsets(Tagged[i][0],'a')` which sense will be return? How to determine the sense?

Comment: Well, it will return all senses. It will return a list of synsets that contain a list of lemmas. Here's an example: http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiwordnet.html Here's how the mapping between WN and SWN is done: https://github.com/bogdan-ivanov/wnext/blob/master/sentiwordnet.py

Comment: This `from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn

happy = swn.senti_synsets('happy', 'a')
for i in happy:
    print(i)` returns `<happy.a.01: PosScore=0.875 NegScore=0.0>
<felicitous.s.02: PosScore=0.75 NegScore=0.0>
<glad.s.02: PosScore=0.5 NegScore=0.0>
<happy.s.04: PosScore=0.125 NegScore=0.0>
` What `s` in `glad.s.02` and why `02` here?

Comment: What do you mean by `Explanatory sentence`?

Comment: A sentence that explains the sense